# How to instantiate Java class from MATLAB?

Tags: java, matlab

Documented way does not work:

```
>> javaaddpath('../../../build/classes/main/');
>> ls('../../../build/classes/main/')
.         ..        attempts  
>> ls('../../../build/classes/main/attempts')
.                    ..                   ImageViewer$1.class  ImageViewer.class    
>> import attempts.ImageViewer;
Error using import
Import argument 'attempts.ImageViewer' cannot be found or cannot be imported.
>> iv = attempts.ImageViewer
Undefined variable "attempts" or class "attempts.ImageViewer".
```

**UPDATE**

More obvious view of not working:

[image]

Since current directory is on the path, it should work. But it doesn't.

**UPDATE 2**

Versions:

```
javap -verbose ImageViewer.class | findstr "major"
  major version: 51

>> version -java
ans =
Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
```

Comment: Either the above duplicate or this one is acceptable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983324/calling-java-from-matlab.  Use either the above or this link to solve your problem.

Comment: As you see it just does not work without any error message. Don't see any explanations in "duplicates"

Comment: I beg to differ. Try out the instructions of each of the highest rated answers in each duplicate **exactly** as laid out and it will work. I don't see fit to reopen this question. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that the Java version you are building your classes with **must be compatible** with the Java version that is shipped with MATLAB.  If the Java class is compiled with a version **newer** than the one shipped with MATLAB, it will not work.  See this comment for more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520503/calling-java-from-matlab#comment32303941_9521010

Comment: I don't need examples to work, I need my class to work. Sure you can leave question closed. Don't see any reason to solve this problem for those who does not have it

Comment: @rayryeng if version would be newer, it would throw classdef exception, as it said in duplicates.

Comment: What "classdef exception" would you expect? classdef is related to matlab classes, not to java classes. Please double check the version, I am sure you used the wrong java version to create the class files. You can display the java version using the `ver` command.

Comment: You can't state that not matching JVM causes no any error message but just silently not works.

Comment: Why do you refuse to simply check the version?

Comment: I checked it as I can, it's 1.7, MATLAB's is newer